# Passing Serializated parameter using $.get method return null in controller method

Tags: jquery, json, model-view-controller, serialization

I have passed serializated object as parameter using $.get method in MVC 4.0

```
$('#btnGenerateReport').click(function () {
    // get filter data
    var reportType = $('input[name=rtype]:radio:checked').val();
    var towerlist = '',
        streamList = '',
        resourceList = '',
        projectList = '';
    $("#selectTower").multiselect("getChecked").each(function (index, object) {
        towerlist = towerlist + $(object).val() + ','
    });

    var o = new Object();
    o.TowerId = towerlist;    

    $.get('@Url.Action("Resource", "Report")', {
        'filterList': JSON.stringify(o)
    }, function (data) {
        $('#report').replaceWith(data);
        $('div.well').hide();
    });
});
```

But it always return filterList null in controller method

```
 public ActionResult Resource(ResourceReport filterList)
    {
        var t = filterList.TowerId;
        var report = resourceReportService.GetResourceReport();
        return View("ResourceReport",report);
    }
```

I have included the `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` namespace

Comment: Any reason you're calling `JSON.stringify(o)` ? Try jsut doing `{filterList: {TowerId:towerList}`.

Comment: there are number of parameters I have to pass, So I included all in ResourceReport  class.